# How to get information on TypeError coming from a library?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

My flex project uses a small swc library. It runs under Flash Builder.

While running the application in debug mode I can see plenty of "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." displayed in console.
But I have no extra information: which method or property caused the error, on which type, where, etc.

My flex app has an uncaught error mechanism, but no error is caught.

I tried to set compiler option "-debug" to true but no change occurred, logs are not more verbose.

I got the library sources and looked for an Error handling where this log would be written, but I found nothing.

Somebody already encountered such issue?

Comment: If you can pinpoint where the call stack leading to the exception originates in your code, you can wrap that piece of code in a try/catch block. This might provide you with more information.

Comment: Not so simple, the errors occur in a graphical element, instantiate in MXML so I can't try/catch it.

Comment: Does it happen when the element is created or after some user interaction?

Comment: It happens after the creation, when the component (a calendar) is given a dataProvider, so I guess it tries to get a property on the data type which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup, you'll have to inspect the data in your dataProvider for nullpointers. Or perhaps the data is not structured the way your calendar component expects it.